# formula for the destination point given the arc length of parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Finding the arc length between a point on a parabola and its vertex is a well documented process:

\begin{align}
h&=\frac{p}{2}\\
q&=\sqrt{f^2+h^2}\\
s&=\frac{hq}{f}+f\ln\left(\frac{h+q}{f}\right)
\end{align}

Where $f$ is the focal length and $p$ is the perpendicular distance from the point to the axis of symmetry of the parabola.

How do i derive the inverse of this formula? One that would allow finding the destination point given the arc length starting from the vertex.
I tried and quickly failed to isolate $p$ as the deadly combination of square roots and logarithms quickly grows out of control at least for my abilities.

Comment: I guess that only numerical methods would solve the problem. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312754/find-a-point-along-a-curve-a-distance-l-away-from-a-known-point/2313092#2313092